# Multiple "details" sections under a group in Access

Tags: database, ms-access

My Data is organized like so:

- Root Task

  - SubTask1
- Root Task2

  - SubTask2
- Root Task3

When creating a report in Access, grouping by root task and adding subtask under details seems to work, but RootTask3 would not show up because it there is no SubTask that refers to it.

How could I organize a report/grouping such that it shows Root Tasks even if they do not have SubTasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default `INNER JOIN` only shows rows where there is a matching record in the other table, but a `LEFT JOIN` in the query used to select data will give the row from the main table, even if there is no matching record in the secondary table.

If you look at the SQL view of your query, you will see the `JOIN`.
If you are looking at the query in the default design mode, right click and select `Join Properties` to choose what records are returned.